# Fitting and extrapolating one curve on other

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, scipy

I have two graphs-

[image]

[image]

The first graph is a data of 3 months and the second one is of 2 weeks. Now I want to extend the data of the second graph to 3 months in the manner(shape) of the first graph. How do I do that?

I was thinking If I find the equation of the 1st graph and then use that to plot the 2nd graph but I dont know how to go on about that.

Comment: IMHO, this is just too broad of a question.

Comment: There are many ways to model the first graph. You need to decide whether you want to model it as an exponential, linear or polynomial curve or some other function entirely. Once you've decided that, then you can extrapolate that model.

As a starting point, you might want to do some reading about the SIR model (assuming you're trying to predict the growth of coronavirus cases).